# malloc.c assertion failed while working with strtok_r

Tags: c, strtok, assertion

I have made an UDP server in C (Ubuntu 10.10). The server is quite large and part of it does some String processing using Strtok_r() [I have used this function successfully before]. When the server runs for the first time, it processes the data from the client correctly. But when another client comes along and sends some data, the program crashes with the following message:

```
MappingServer: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

If I comment out the strtok_r() function then everything works properly (No matter how many clients r coming!). The code that's causing the problem is:

```
char delims[] = "/"; 
char* token = NULL; 
char* separated_token[4]; 
int i,j; 
char* last; 
j = 0; 
token = strtok_r( input_string, delims, &last );
       while( token != NULL)
       {
        separated_token[j] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        strcpy(separated_token[j],token);
        printf("%s  ", separated_token[j] );

        j++;
        token = strtok_r( NULL, delims, &last );
        }
```

As far as I can understand, the code is OK and it works perfectly for the first client. I am a little confused, what does this error mean? I have tried with strtok() and the result is the same.

Comment: The most likely cause for the assert is writing off the end of a `malloc`d block.  One possibility: is `seperated_token` also `malloc`d?  Is it long enough?

Comment: You need to give more code for us to diagnose..sounds like something is up with `separated_token` though.

Comment: @user Pet peeve of mine, but please give your questions a descriptive title. "Weird error in C" tells us nothing about the actual question.

Comment: What'll happen if you receive more than 4 tokens ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion
```

This means that internal malloc structures in the heap are broken. Try to run you server in the `valgrind` to find heap usage error and/or memory corruption.

The code you added is hard to analyse, because there is not code with will do a `free()`; the size of `separated_token[]` array is not known. Do you free() all tokens after processing? Do you allocate enough elements for the `separated_token[]` array itself? Do you reset `j` counter to zero before start tokenizing second request?

Comment: @user676987 - are you sure you'll never get more than 4 tokens?

Comment: Ok, the code in more detailed way:
char delims[] = "/";
   char* token = NULL;
   char* separated_token[4];
   int i,j;
   char* last;

           
           j = 0;
           token = strtok_r( input_string, delims, &last );
           while( token != NULL)
           {
            separated_token[j] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
            strcpy(separated_token[j],token);
            printf("%s  ", separated_token[j] );

            j++;
            token = strtok_r( NULL, delims, &last );
            }

Comment: `while(token != NULL && j < 4)` could be a good idea anyway; consider also to use `strdup` instead of malloc/strcpy.

Comment: @user676987 No, that's not more detailed, as nobody can read that. Try to update your question and don't post complete C programs in comments. And make sure to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote functionalities!